# multithreading - Need my threaded process to spawn another thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Python 3.x on Ubuntu 16.04

My program is intended to monitor an incoming stream of integers (`data`). 
When the integer is >= 5, I want a new thread to spawn.

This new thread will record the numbers "forever", until the integers fall below 5 again, in which case, the thread should "die".

I want this process to repeat endlessly; every time we hit 5 we spawn a new thread, then kill it.

I have the process `counter` inside its' own thread because eventually I will be putting in a tkinter GUI (pretty self-explanatory there).

I run this code and everything works as planned...

[When we reach 5, a new thread is created!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEqq.png)

[When we fall below 5, the thread stops running `use_data`...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4vZJ.png)

[When we climb back up to 5, nothing happens with respect to creating a new thread.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Q2S.png)

My issue has something to do with not "killing" the previous thread; my thread-check is OK I think, it's supposed to create a new thread if the thread list `threads` is empty, or if the only remaining thread is `_MainThread`. I know the number stream `data` setup probably hurts your eyes, it hurts mine too.

**The Code:**

```
import time
import random
import queue
import threading
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)s):%(message)s')

threads = []
data = list(list(range(10)) + list(reversed(range(10))))

def start_new_thread(thread_name):
    logging.debug('...init thread creator...')
    t = threading.Thread(name=thread_name, target=use_data)
    t.daemon = True
    logging.debug('...starting new thread...')
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    logging.debug('...ALIVE THREADS: {}'.format(threads))

def kill_thread():
    stopFlag.set()

def counter():
    global threads
    global data
    x = 0
    for i in data:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        logging.debug(i)
        if i > 5:
            logging.debug('Flow reached')
            logging.debug('Counter thread: {}'.format(threading.current_thread().getName()))
            start_event.set()
            if not threads:
                logging.debug('Empty thread list; creating a new one...')
                x += 1
                start_new_thread(thread_name='THREAD {}'.format(x))
            elif threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread':
                logging.debug('_MainThread is the only remaining thread; creating a new one...')
                x += 1
                start_new_thread(thread_name='THREAD {}'.format(x))
        else:
            kill_thread()
            start_event.clear()
    counter()

def use_data():
    start_event.wait()
    logging.debug('...Start Func: {}....'.format(threading.current_thread()))
    while start_event.is_set():
        logging.debug('Data thread: {}'.format(threading.current_thread().getName()))
        logging.debug('POLLING...')
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_thread = threading.Thread(name='Process Thread', target=counter)
    start_event = threading.Event()
    stopFlag = threading.Event()
    process_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Your thread-check is not okay

1. You add threads to the thread list when created (`threads.append(t)`), but you never remove them. It would make more sense if you would remove the exiting thread at the end of `use_data` with `threads.remove(threading.current_thread())`. So `if not threads` is never true after you've created one thread.
2. This if statement: `elif threading.current_thread().__class__.__name__ == '_MainThread':` will never trigger because the *main thread* never enters this function. The main thread creates the first thread ('Process Thread') with `target=counter`, then the main thread is done and exits. "Process Thread" is the only thread that ever enters this function anyway so a name comparison is pointless.

So, in sum, your first 'if' won't trigger because `threads` is never empty after the first thread is started. Your second 'if' won't *ever* trigger. Hence, `start_new_thread` will only ever be called once.